# I received a comment from non-existing user

Tags: support, comments, deleted-users

A few minutes ago I received a comment on one of [my posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62146446/8344060) by user which seems to be unregistered or deleted his account right after the post (there is no link to his username)

[image]

This took me a bit by surprise as I understood that you [require to have some reputation to be able to post a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Can someone explain what happened here?

---

<sub>Referenced post deleted, as the answer was low quality.</sub>

Comment: Although improbable, couldn't it be that the user was removed shortly after they posted that comment?

Comment: The user may have had the [Free +100 Site Association Bonus](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The user who left that comment deleted their own account. Self-deletion of the account occurred at 2020-06-02 08:45:25Z; the comment was posted at 2020-06-02 08:45:18Z.

Presumably, this was a transient account created on Stack Overflow by someone already trusted elsewhere on the network, which allowed them to get the association bonus and thus immediate commenting privileges. Once they'd said what they wanted to say, they deleted the account.

<strike>But I don't know that for certain. I can't (and wouldn't want to, even if I could) trace the complete history of that account, so I can't exclude the possibility that it is a long-standing user who just decided to delete their account shortly after leaving that comment to you.</strike> Actually, I can confirm that the now-deleted user account never posted any questions or answers. So it was almost certainly a transient account, granted comment privileges by the association bonus.